# Path not found on PodioAppField::update

Tags: php, podio

I am following the documentation https://developers.podio.com/doc/applications
and the given models from the SDK.

Im trying to add a new app to an existing app reference like so:

```
$attributes = array( 
            "referenced_apps" => array(ref_app_id1 , ref_app_id2)                        
        );

PodioAppField::update( 123 ,  'my_external_id' ,array (
                                                    "settings" => $attributes
                                               ));
```

But will receive the following error

```
Uncaught PodioNotFoundError: "No matching operation could be found. The path '/app/123/field/my_external_id' was not found.."
```

My app_id and external_id are correct.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires field_id instead of external_id.

Comment: Still it seems to me, that there might be a possibility to use the external_id, isn't there? Being able to use the field_id only, is just not consistent when you follow the rest of Podio's API.

Comment: Yes, it's a bit inconsistent when it comes to field related operations. Sometimes we can use both field_id and external_id, sometimes we can't.